# Deploy PPAPI plugins out of Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome, browser-plugin, google-nativeclient, chrome-web-store, ppapi

Is it possible to deploy a PPAPI Chrome plugin without publishing on Chrome Web Store, say, provide an installer to end users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PNaCl without publishing on the Chrome Web Store. PNaCl can load from your web site(s).

But no, Chrome doesn't support you having an installer for a PPAPI plugin that was not built with the NaCl or PNaCl toolchain.